# My applicationWillEnterForeground function is not working in iOS 13. What can I do?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, multitasking, unusernotificationcenter

I want to delete all local notifications from the notification center when the app enters the foreground. I used the `applicationWillEnterForeground` function in the App Delegate:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // To remove all delivered notifications
    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
}
```

Unfortunately the function does not run. I read somewhere that the reason for that could be the multitasking in iOS. My question is how can I turn off multitasking? Or if somebody has another idea why the function does not run.

Comment: It’s the scene delegate now, instead of the app delegate.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene)` method in `sceneDelegate` for this if your `applicationWillEnterForeground` is not working